# How to iterate through enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum for various operations, I want to iterate through the enum `Operations`

```
public enum Operations 
{
create,update,delete,view,compare,login
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It is important--not just convenient--to iterate through an enum's values. Doing so prevents future failures when values are added or deleted.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
for (Operations op : Operations.values()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also when i try `for (Operations op : Operations.values()) {
     if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(op.name()))
     {
      op=Operations.valueOf(arr[0].toLowerCase());
      log.info(arr[0].toString());
     }     
    }` it does not seem to work

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: What is that code supposed to do? What is `arr[0]`? Why are you reassigning `op`?

Comment: arr[0] is coming from parameterMap `String[] arr=(String[])me.getValue();` I am supposing that `op=Operations.valueOf(arr[0].toLowerCase())` means it is the current selected `operation` What i am trying to do is, if parameterMap contains any of the operations then execute set of statements

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: The assignment is redundant: you're checking already in the `if` statement whether `arr[0]` equals the current `op`'s name (case ignored), so there you have the current selected operation - it's `op`. How is it not working? Try print statements to see what `arr[0]` actually contains.